# Make Title Field get its content from a people picker field

Tags: list, custom

I need to create a list of people and the name of the person should be unique field that can be clicked to open the item about that person.

In a normal Sharepoint 2010 custom list, the Title field is always used as the reference unique entry which allows an item to be clicked but it's locked to a text field.

If I remove the Title field and use a People Picker field, clicking on the name would open the profile of that person and not the list item.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When creating you views you can add the attribute ListItemMenu to the field in the viewfields section:

```
<ViewFields>
  ...
  <FieldRef Name="XXX" ListItemMenu="TRUE"/>
  ...
</ViewFields>
```

The name will still link to the profile, but you get the dropdown menu for selecting everything you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSL transformation for change rendering template of list view.[This post](http://www.intheknow.it/Default.aspx?Page=customxsltfieldrendering&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) can give you a start point to search how could you do this change.